# how to change main activity variables in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am creating a activity having two fragment .
one for summation-substraction
other for displaying total value
the main activity contains variable (total) 
if in fragment the value is sum then variable (total) is increased by entered value otherwise it is decreased by entered value

and this variable (total) is displayed in second fragment

Answer (score 1):

you can use interface for get and set data into fragment with activity . or you can create the static variable and call it from class name like this in mainActivity

```
public static int total=0
```

in fragment where you want to call and change its value just call like this `MainActivity.total=your value`

Answer (score 1):

Put this function in your activity:

```
public void setTotal(int newTotal) {
this.total = newTotal;
}
```

Then call this in your fragment:

`((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).setTotal(newTotal);`

Although I would suggest you storing variables that you need app wide in shared preferences or Room if you have many variables. Or using bundles to send data between activitys/fragments.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```
//activity
    val variable=0

//fragment
    activity?.variable = newValue
```

Solution 2: 
Use Singleton Class

```
object AppData{
    val variable=0
}

//activity : use the variable
AppData.variable

//fragment
AppData.variable = newValue
```

Solution 3: (Recommended)
Use MVVM

```
class ActivityVM : ViewModel {
        val variable = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    }

//activity
activityVM= ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(ActivityVM::class.java)

activityVM.variable.observe(this,Observer{ 
//it <- value
})

//fragemnt
activityVM= ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(ActivityVM::class.java)
activityVM.variable.postValue(newValue)
```